# How to declare a global variable in a module

Tags: python, global-variables

In the main program I have

```
import medallia_utils
from collections import defaultdict
Opers   = defaultdict(int)
```

Later on in this program, I will be calling a function in medallia_utils called word_checker.

I want to manipulate the dictionary variable Opers in a function word_checker defined inside medallia_utils so I want to declare it as Global.

When I do this inside of medallia_utils:

```
def word_checker(name, comment):
    import re 
    from collections import defaultdict
    global Opers
```

The system says

```
NameError: global name 'Opers' is not defined
```

I also tried to define this variable globally in medallia_utils outside of the function word_checker by doing

```
global Opers
```

or

```
global __Opers__
```

but nothing working so far. I get the same error.

What is the syntax fix to get this to work?

Comment: How do you do this? You don't. Avoid globals as much as you can. Import it, inject it, or find some other way to get data in wherever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "syntax fix" that can make this work. If you want to use a variable defined in another module, you need to import it.

Comment: I am having problems.  When I define a dictionary locally in an imported module, and I try to "return" it at the end of a function in that module, the main function reports an empty dictionary although I can see via print statements in the imported module it is not empty.  So I was trying to declare a variable globally to allow the imported module to operate on it.

Comment: That is not the solution. You should work out why your dict is becoming empty.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make the variable hold something after you declare it as global eg.

```
global name 
name = 'bob'
```